# About the decay of Higgs into 2 $Z$-bosons

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, feynman-diagrams, higgs

I need to know if I understand this point.

The factor of $HZZ$ vertex in the SM Lagrangian is half the value of the Feynman rule which appears in Diagrammatica.

When I calculate the decay of Higgs into 2 Z, I have to integrate over only half the phase space, because the two Z's are identical.

So, at the end, I get the same result as if I took the exact Lagrangian factor and integrated over the entire phase space, i.e. $2\cdot0.5=1$.

But, in the second way, I would in fact do two mistakes which cancel each other and accidentally get the correct answer.
Is this correct?

Comment: It's very strange how you're canceling mistakes against correct factors. The SM Lagrangian at two places is either equivalent up to a field redefinition or one of the places are wrong. Moreover, the decay width is proportional to the squared amplitude, so if the amplitude is doubled by a factor of 2 error at the beginning, then the probabilities and decay rates will be quadrupled ie changed by a factor of 4 which doesn't cancel against 2.

Comment: To add to what Lubos said, I think we might need to see the actual coefficients of the HZZ vertex and of the Feynman rule you're talking about in order to give a sensible answer to this question.

Comment: Thanks Lubos. It's 4*0.5 as you said, I didn't sqaure the amplitude.

Answer (score 1):

The Higgs boson can decay into two Z boson because the coupling strength between the Higgs bosons and the Z boson is quite strong. This means the Higgs could decay into a Z boson with spin 1 and spin -1. This will add up to the Higgs spin of 0. This is because the Z boson is the third most massive particle. Only less massive than the top quark and the Higgs itself.